# Multiple domains issue

Tags: plugins, multisite, domain

we have a wordpress site that has been blocked in some countries in Middle East. so we bought a new domain and pointed it to the same root folder. the homepage is showing with the new domain but all the pictures, external codes, and link are blocked due to the fact that they are referring to the first domain.

so, in short, what i want is:

- when a user visits: [www.firstdomain.com] i want the contents of the page are all referring to the same domain, like [www.firstdomain.com/articles/1253/]
- but when a user visits: [www.seconddomain.com] i want the contents of the page are referring to the second domain, like [www.seconddomain.com/articles/1253]

is that possible using wordpress alone? or should i install a caching script in the second domain?

Comment: Is it the domain or the IP being blocked? I would suspect it's the latter, making circumvention more difficult.

Comment: Where is the domain hosted? Some places such as GoDaddy offer forwarding with "Masking", which may or may not also mask the resources that are loading.

Comment: What got your site blocked?

Comment: @Dan no it's just the domain, I opened the new domain in their server and it's working.

Comment: @TomJNowell It's an atheists network.

Comment: I think it's DOMAINCONTROL.COM or something

Comment: You may wish to consider a mirroring setup then, such as repress until you have a solution setup

Answer (score 0):

It is rather easy to make WP think it is served from different domain by defining `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants in configuration dynamically for request. See [Editing wp-config.php in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29) for details.

However this only affects dynamically generated elements. Everything that is part of content isn't modified by this, including but not limited to content of posts.

Depending on your setup (server, caching, etc) it might be approached on different levels — from filtering inside WordPress to buffering and rewriting page on PHP level, and so on.